# Effects of eating rice at dinner time

Tags: nutrition, digestion, supplement, time-of-day, meal

I have heard the claim that eating rice during dinner is not good for ones health.
Is this true?  What is the impact of eating rice in night?

Answer (score 3):

The glycemic index of rice varies quite a lot: according to [this link](http://www.health.harvard.edu/diseases-and-conditions/glycemic-index-and-glycemic-load-for-100-foods) from Harvard Medical School, from 38 for Parboiled rice to 72 for white rice. The latter is a rather high glycemic index. As a consequence, it may be that white rice at dinner releases glucose rapidly, and what is not needed then gets stored as fat. 
Of course, this depends on a number of factors, like how much rice do you eat, what sort of rice it is (there are many!), whether your dinner has been preceded or is followed by physical activity, and so on. Generally, I would reject the claim that eating rice during dinner is not good for one's health.